# Checkout as guest setting name, lastname and email

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, guest-checkout

I am creating a module who comunicates with [Visa Checkout](http://developer.visa.com/products/visa_checkout/reference). When customer select Visa Checkout on cart I am setting this data:

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()
            ->setCustomerFirstname($firstname)
            ->setCustomerLastname($lastname)
            ->setCustomerEmail($email)
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
            ->save();
```

After this I redirect tthe customer to onepage and fill payment data (previously returned from Visa Checkout). I have modified the onepage to don't have billing and shipping information.

But when customer place the order an user is created. How can I disable the customer creation?

Comment: I tried to force the onepage too:
$this->getOnepage()->saveCheckoutMethod(Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_GUEST);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forced this on onepage module (as mentioned on comment):

```
$this->getOnepage()->saveCheckoutMethod(Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD‌​_GUEST);
```

And add this on my custom module:

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()
            ->setCustomerFirstname($firstname)
            ->setCustomerLastname($lastname)
            ->setCustomerEmail($email)
            ->setCheckoutMethod(Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_GUEST)
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
            ->save();
```

This solved my problem.